# Maximizing $|\langle x, v \rangle|$ given $\| M x\|_2 = C$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose we are given a matrix $M \in \mathbb C^{m \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb C^n$.
We want to maximize $|\langle z, v\rangle |$, assuming that $\|Mz\|_2 = C$.

It does not seem too difficult. However, I'm not sure where to start given that we are dealing with complex parameters. For instnace, is the problem convex? What would convex mean in this context?

Comment: If $v\notin (\ker M)^\perp $ then the maximum is infinite. So we should assume that $v\in (\ker M)^\perp.$

Comment: Hint: If $A = M^{-1}$ exists, this is equivalent to maximizing $|\langle Az, v\rangle |^2$ subject to $\|z\|^2 = z^*z = C^2$. Now use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @HansEngler In this case the Lagrange multiplier method can be avoided: the maximum is equal $C\|(M^{-1})^*v\|.$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0\neq v\in {\rm Im}\, M^*.$ Then there is a unique $0\neq w\in{\rm Im}\, M=(\ker M^*)^\perp$ such that $M^*w=v.$ Moreover
$$|\langle z,v\rangle |=|\langle z,M^*w\rangle |=|\langle Mz, w\rangle|\le \|Mz\|\,\|w\|= C\|w\|$$
Hence the maximum is less than or equal $C\|w\|=C\|Mz_0\|.$
As $w\in {\rm Im}\,M$ we have $Mz_0=w$ for some $z_0.$ For $z={C\over \|w\|}z_0={C\over \|Mz_0\|}z_0$ we obtain $\|Mz\|=C$ and $$\langle z,v\rangle ={C\over \|w\|}\langle z_0,M^*w\rangle ={C\over \|w\|}\langle Mz_0,w\rangle =C\|w\|$$
Hence the maximum is equal $C\|w\|=C\|Mz_0\|.$

If $v\notin {\rm Im}\, M^*$ then $v=v_1+v_2,$ where $ v_1\in {\rm Im}\, M^*$ and $0\neq v_2\in \ker M=({\rm Im}\, M^*)^\perp.$ Then   $$\sup_{\|Mz\|=C}|\langle z,v\rangle|=\infty$$ as replacing $z$ with $z+tv_2$ gives $\|M(z+tv_2)\|=C$ and $$\langle z+tv_2,v\rangle =\langle z,v_2\rangle +t\|v_2\|^2$$
**Summarizing** In order to determine the maximum we find a solution of  the equation $M^*Mz=v.$ Then the maximal value is equal $C\|Mz\|.$

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to a quadratic problem in $\mathbb R^{2n}$. Indeed write $v = u + iw$, $x = y + iz$ and $M = A + iB$ where $i^2 = -1$ the problem is equivalent to:

$$\max_{y, z \in \mathbb R^{n}}\, \left\|\begin{bmatrix}u^T & w^T\\ w^T &-u^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y \\ z\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2\;:\; \left\|\begin{bmatrix}A & -B\\ B & A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2 = C$$

If you had an inequality constraint instead of equality constraint the problem becomes a quadratic convex problem:

$$\max_{y, z \in \mathbb R^{n}}\, \left\|\begin{bmatrix}u^T & w^T\\ w^T &-u^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y \\ z\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2\;:\; \left\|\begin{bmatrix}A & -B\\ B & A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2 \le C$$